# Python: error in module importation

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to install basemap module for python (2.7).
I already add the path (~/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap) in PYTHONPATH, and in sys.path but I'm unable to import basemap module.

> from mpl_toolkits import basemap
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "testmap.py", line 17, in 
>       from mpl_toolkits import basemap
>   ImportError: cannot import name basemap

I've also tried to do the same thing with a simple file:

> def hello1():
>
> print 'HelloWorld!'

I can't import this one either, so it doesn't seems to come from an error in basemap installation.

Comment: Whick version of `mpl_toolkits` is it ?

Comment: did you install using `pip` ?

Comment: No i've used easy-install. i'm using matplotlib version 1.4.0.